# Алгоритмы построения магических квадратов

Tags: алгоритм

Есть куча алгоритмов построения четных-четных и четных-нечетных совершенных магических квадратов, а мне надо единый алгоритм для построения не совершенных (важны только одинаковые суммы по строкам, столбцам и главным диагоналям) четных квадратов. Существует ли такой?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То, что Вы называете "несовершенным магическим квадратом", называется "полумагическим".
Единого алгоритма пока неизвестно. Для нечетных - там есть единый алгоритм, а вот для четных - там уже нет.

Хотя я погорячился, метод есть, называется "полный перебор". Но его можно сильно оптимизировать. Припустим, что у нас есть квадрат с размером стороны `n`. Тогда полный перебор всех вариантов - `(n*n)!` - многовато. Но если сделать перебор только для одной строки, то вариантов будет заметно меньше. Где то `(n*n)!/(n*n-n+1))!`. То есть, переформулируя (если в формуле ошибся), для 6на6 квадрата нужно перебрать `36*35*34*33*32` (шестое число подбирается по сумме).

Итого, вместо `3*10^41` получится `(45*10^6)^5 = 1,8*10^38` - не сильно меньше, но все же... Но я не учитывал, что цифры не должны повторятся, поэтому должно быть сильно меньше.

Но нужно понимать, что нам то не нужно все варианты перебрать, а только первый рабочий, поэтому не все так страшно.

Можно подумать ещё об сокращениях.

Comment: спасибо, есть с чего начать :) что означает "!" после выражения?

Comment: [Факториал][1]


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB